# Variable defined according to entire document contents

Tags: counters

I would like to define and use a variable in my title page. This variable depends on the contents of the entire document. For illustration purposes, the variable could be a counter that is incremented throughout the document. When the document is compiled I want the variable to contain the total value of all increments in the document---even when it is used at the beginning of the document. That is, I want to sum all increments at the beginning of the file.

For example, something like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\x{0}
\begin{document}

\sumOfAllIncrements
\incrementX
\sumOfAllIncrements
\incrementX
\incrementX
\sumOfAllIncrements

\end{document}
```

Needs to output

```
3
3
3
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You should consider the `totcount` package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real need to use [`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount), but it allows you to perform calculations with the reference, if that's needed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{refcount}

\newcounter{Xcntr}
\newcommand{\incrementX}{\stepcounter{Xcntr}}% Increment Xcntr
\newcommand{\sumOfAllIncrements}{\getrefnumber{Xcntr}}% Retrieve Xcntr
\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{\edef\@currentlabel{\theXcntr}\label{Xcntr}}% Update reference and \label it
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\sumOfAllIncrements

\incrementX

\sumOfAllIncrements

\incrementX

\incrementX

\sumOfAllIncrements

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well! That was certainly fast and effective!

Comment: I've adapted your idea to my particular use. It works perfectly. Many thanks!